# How to return all float values ​from an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, intellij-idea, return

I only return the last value, please, help me to return all values

```
public static float[] generatePatientsTemperatures(int patientsCount) {
        float[] patientsTemperature = new float[patientsCount];
        for (int i = 1; i < patientsCount; i++) {
            patientsTemperature[i] = Math.round(((float) (Math.random() * 8) + 32) * 100) / (float) 100.0;
        }
    
        return patientsTemperature;
```

Comment: You are returning the array which means you're already returning all values. Maybe you want to print the values or perform another operation on them?

Comment: You should initialize i to 0, in order to assign values to all the elements of the array.

Comment: You are retunring array, how that possibly is last value? It has all values from 1 to patientsCount - 1.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

If you asking why your resulting array has one less element than expected, it is because of your initialization of `i` variable in your `for` loop.

➥ Change `int i = 1` to `int i = 0`.

## An array *does* hold all values

You are returning all the values. That is what an array does: holds a series of values. Your code successfully returns an array full of `float` primitive values.

### Example code

I suggest using [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) rather than `Math.random` because it offers some simple and handy methods. And it makes you future-proof if you ever do multi-threading.

You need to change your `i = 1` to `i = 0` to get the right number of elements in your results. Perhaps this is what your Question meant to ask, “Why am I getting one less element in my array than expected?”. Your initialization of `i` would be the cause of that problem.

```java
public static float[] generatePatientsTemperatures ( final int patientsCount )
{
    float[] patientsTemperature = new float[ patientsCount ];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < patientsCount ; i++ )
    {
        patientsTemperature[ i ] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(320,450) * 0.1F;
    }
    return patientsTemperature;
}
```

Try that code. To see all the values of the array as text, call the utility method `Arrays.toString( yourArrayHere )`.

```java
float[] temps = App.generatePatientsTemperatures( 3 );
String output = Arrays.toString( temps );
```

When run:

> output = [35.5, 37.100002, 34.3]

Access each element in the array by annoying zero-based counting: zero for the first element, 1 for the second element, and so on.

```java
float first = temps[ 0 ] ;
float second = temps[ 1 ] ;
float third = temps[ 2 ] ;
```

---

## `List`

Working with `List` is easier than array.

`List` holds object references only, no primitive values allowed. Java has an auto-boxing feature to automatically turn your `float` primitives into `Float` objects. Just redefine your array to hold `Float` rather than `float`.

Tip: `List.of` produces an [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) collection.

```java
public static List < Float > generatePatientsTemperatures ( final int patientsCount )
{
    Float[] patientsTemperature = new Float[ patientsCount ];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < patientsCount ; i++ )
    {
        patientsTemperature[ i ] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 320 , 450 ) * 0.1F;  // Auto-boxed from `float` primitive to `Float` object.
    }
    List < Float > results = List.of( patientsTemperature );
    return results;
}
```

Some code to run it.

```java
List < Float > temps = App.generatePatientsTemperatures( 3 );
String output = temps.toString();
```

> output = [32.8, 43.600002, 35.5]

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying in another method to get the whole array, but it only gives out the last value. How to display all values ​​of an array in another method?

Comment: @ArturKnyazev ??? I just wrote this Answer showing you exactly that.